# map() function does not seem to be doing what it is supposed to do

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to display a bunch of tkinter labels on the screen by storing the text and the other things like the value of `padx` and `pady` for that widget in a tuple nested within a list. I'm trying to iterate through each element of the list and display the label using the `map()` function. Here is a minimum example of my code

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk


def func() :
    print("in func")
    def populate(tple) :
        print(f"In populate with tuple {tple}")
        label = ttk.Label(frame,text=tple[0],style=tple[1])
        label.grid(row=lst.index(tple),column=0,padx=tple[2],pady=tple[3],sticky=tple[4])
        frame.update_idletasks()

    tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, 0, weight=1)
    lst = [("This is text1","style1.TLabel",40,15,None),
        ("This is text2","style2.TLabel",20,15,tk.S)]
    map(populate, lst)

frame = ThemedTk(theme="black")
frame.config(bg="#424242")
style = ttk.Styles()
func()

frame.mainloop()
```

But for some reason, `map()` does not seem to be working. My question is, why is that? Is it because I'm not using `map()` like I'm supposed to? If so, how do I correctly use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` will just return an iterator which need to be consumed in order to apply the function passed.  Use something like `list()` or `all()` to consume it:

```py
all(map(populate, lst))
```

Comment: Thanks! using ```list()``` fixed it for me

Comment: And now you create a return value and a list you don't need. Why not just `for entry in lst: populate(entry)`?

Comment: I do realise that i dont need to use ```map()``` and could just use a simpIe for loop but I was just learning ```map()``` so I wanted to write a few programs using it.